# Script to output the resolved hostnames to a file

Tags: batch-file, ip, hostname, resolve

Im looking for a script (batch, perl, vb or whatever) that will resolve the hostnames i will give to it into IPS and output a file(optionally) with them, just as the Windows Hosts File.

So for example, when i give to it: www.stackoverflow.com

it will output to a file (or even in screen, with echo) this line:

69.59.197.21 www.stackoverflow.com

Thanks in advance! Happy new Year!
Cheers

Comment: in linux u can just try this :> host www.stackoverflow.com | grep "has"

Comment: thanks, but this will output "www.stackoverflow.com has the address 69.59.197.21".

any way to get an output of "69.59.197.21 is the address of www.stackoverflow.com" so i can mass remove "is the address of" and use it as hosts file on windows?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /p hostname=Enter hostname: 
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('ping %hostname% ^| find "Pinging"') do (
set ip=%%a
set ip=!ip:[=!
set ip=!ip:]=!
echo !ip! %hostname%
)
pause >nul
```

Comment: Thank you Bali C! I noticed that many websites use subdomains on different ip.

Is there a way to browse to the sites by browser and export the dns cache in proper for the hosts file format? I tried ipconfig /displaydns >C:\test.txt which works fine, but the output is not proper for hosts

Comment: Sorry, I don't get that second part. So is there a particular part of `ipconfig /displaydns` that you want to extract?

Comment: Also, @user1948608 if you liked Bali's answer it would help him out if you clicked the check next to it and gave him credit for it!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in linux

```
**print address and hostname**

    [user@server scripts]$ host www.stackoverflow.com | grep "has add" | awk '{print $1}{print $4}' 
    stackoverflow.com
    69.59.197.21

**Print address only**

    [user@server scripts]$ host www.stackoverflow.com | grep "has add" | awk '{print $4}' 
    69.59.197.21


**Append To File**

    [user@server scripts]$ host www.stackoverflow.com | grep "has add" | awk '{print $4}' >> hosts.list
```

Hope this helps ( in *nix )